# How to determine if CGFloat is Float or Double

Tags: swift, quartz-graphics, quartz-core, accelerate-framework, cgfloat

Quartz uses `CGFloat` for its graphics. `CGFloat` is either `Float` or `Double`, depending on the processor.

The Accelerate framework has different variations of the same function. 
For example dgetrf_ for Double's and sgetrf_ for Float's.

I have to make these two work together. Either I can use Double's everywhere and convert them to CGFloat every time I use quartz, or I can (try to) determine the actual type of CGFloat and use the appropriate Accelerate function.

Mixing `CGFloat's` and `Double` types all over my code base is not very appealing and converting thousands or millions of values to CGFloat every time doesn't strike me as very efficient either.

At this moment I would go with the second option. (Or shouldn't I?)

My question is: how do I know the actual type of `CGFloat`?

```
if ??? //pseudo-code: CGFloat is Double
{
   dgetrf_(...)
}
else
{
   sgetrf_(...)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Documentation on Swift Floating-Point Numbers:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID321)

> Floating-point types can represent a much wider range of values than
>   integer types, and can store numbers that are much larger or smaller
>   than can be stored in an Int. Swift provides two signed floating-point
>   number types:
>
> - Double represents a 64-bit floating-point number.
> - Float represents a 32-bit floating-point number.

You can test using the `sizeof` function:

```
if sizeof(CGFloat) == sizeof(Double) {
  // CGFloat is a Double
} else {
  // CGFloat is a Float
}
```

Probably the easiest way to deal with this is to use conditional compilation to define a wrapper which will call the proper version:

```
import Accelerate

func getrf_(__m: UnsafeMutablePointer<__CLPK_integer>,
            __n: UnsafeMutablePointer<__CLPK_integer>,
            __a: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>,
            __lda: UnsafeMutablePointer<__CLPK_integer>,
            __ipiv: UnsafeMutablePointer<__CLPK_integer>,
            __info: UnsafeMutablePointer<__CLPK_integer>) -> Int32 {

  #if __LP64__ // CGFloat is Double on 64 bit archetecture
    return dgetrf_(__m, __n, UnsafeMutablePointer<__CLPK_doublereal>(__a), __lda, __ipiv, __info)
  #else
    return sgetrf_(__m, __n, UnsafeMutablePointer<__CLPK_real>(__a), __lda, __ipiv, __info)
  #endif
}
```

Comment: You can just test \__LP64\__ here instead of x86_64 + arm64.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE` macro defined in Core Graphics. You can use it in Swift for direct comparison:

```
if CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE == 1 {
   print("Double") 
} else {
   print("Float")
}
```

Of course, direct size comparison is also possible:

```
if sizeof(CGFloat) == sizeof(Double) {            
}
```

However, since there are overloaded functions for all `Float`, `Double` and `CGFloat`, there is rarely a reason to inspect the size of the type.

Comment: I was just editing my answer to use `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE`. I didn't know about it until I was just poking around. Good call on using both sizes to direct compare.

Comment: @ColGraff Unfortunately it doesn't seem it is possible to use it in conditional compilation. We can check only that it's defined... which is always.

Comment: Ahh, yep. I thought there was a reason it couldn't be used like that. Too bad.